# How do I use phonenumber module from pip3 in VSC?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

[image: I am trying to run this (phonenumbers) module from pip3, but the code will not recognize the (phonenumbers) module.]

Can you help me be effective with this program?

[image]

Comment: Don't show us images.  Cut-and-paste your source code into the question, and cut-and-paste the traceaback, which we cannot see at all.

Comment: You have not defined the variable `number`

Comment: whats the traceback?

Comment: import phonenumbers
from test import izzy
 
from phonenumbers import geocoder
ch_nmber = phonenumbers.parse(izzy, "CH")
print(geocoder.description_for_number(ch_nmber, "en"))

Comment: Please put the exact error message that you got after executing the program

Comment: @SamVarghese I think it was supposed to be Izzy, from "test import izzyy"

Comment: Problem sorted??

Comment: Lunandas-MacBook-Air:Phone Number lunandaroberttamimi$  cd "/Users/lunandaroberttamimi/Phone Number" ; /usr/bin/env /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 /Users/lunandaroberttamimi/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.5.926500501/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 57940 -- "/Users/lunandaroberttamimi/Phone Number/Main.py"

Comment: It should provide the City of the area code from the phone number I provided

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal

```
pip install phonenumbers
```

Implementation

```
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> x = phonenumbers.parse("5514596990","MX")
>>> print(x)
```

Output

```
Country Code: 52 National Number: 5514596990
```

Comment: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 "/Users/lunandaroberttamimi/Phone Number/Main.py
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Lunandas-MacBook-Air:Phone Number lunandaroberttamimi$ /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 "/Users/lunandaroberttamimi/Phone Number/Main.py" 
Lunandas-MacBook-Air:Phone Number lunandaroberttamimi$

Comment: Nothing is showing up when I run the program

Comment: Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder

ch_number = phonenumbers.parse("0431234567", "CH")

print(ch_number)
print(geocoder.description_for_number(ch_number, "en"))
print(geocoder.description_for_number(ch_number, "de"))
```

First, remove the line of `from test import izzy`.

Second:

> You might want to get some information about the location that
> corresponds to a phone number. The
> geocoder.area_description_for_number does this, **when possible**.